1g=.602x10(23) amu?
1) 6.02 x 10 (23) amu is same as 6.02 x 10 (23) atoms?
1 mole is 6.02 x 10 (23). It can be atoms or molecules or particles regardless of atoms gram like 12 bananas is dozen regardless 12 bananas weight because each bannas weight cane be different.
For example, 18.016g of H2O atoms is one more
14.01 g  of N is one mole.

atoms mass unit is amu (u)
Conversion factor from atoms mass unit to grams?

in my text book, it is written that 1g =6.02x10(13) but I thought I mole=6.02x10(23) and one moles can be grams anything depending on atoms.
Like H is 1.008g and N is 14.01g.


So Why is 1 gram=6.02x10(23) in my textbook and how does it become from amu to gram??
Wen 12 grams of carbon is 6.02x10(23)

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure. // If you searched for it, you would not need to ask.

Consider formatting guides for texts and formulas/equations/expressions

You should write $\pu{6.022E23}$ as $\pu{6.022E23}$  ( exactly $\pu{6.02214076E23}$ )

I will simply correct and improve your statements.

One amu is a mass. $\ce{6.023 10^{23}}≠$ is not a mass. It is a number. Masses cannot be equal to numbers. One amu is the mass of $1/12$ Carbon-$12$ atom. $\ce{6.012 10^{23}}$ amu is the same as the mass of $\ce{6.012 10^{23}}$ atoms (Carbon-12/12). It is not the mass of $\ce{6.012 10^{23}}$ any atoms.
In the example, you state that $18.016$ g $\ce{H2O}$ is one mole. No ! It is the mass of one mole $\ce{H2O}$. You also state that that $14.01$ g N is one mole of N. No ! It is not one mole N. It is the mass of one mole nitrogen.

In your textbook, it is written that $1$ g is $\ce{6.023 10^{23}}$. No ! This sentence is not finished. It should be written that $1$ g is $\ce{6.023 10^{23}}$ amu, or $\ce{6.023 10^{23}}$ times the mass of $1/12$ of the mass of the Carbon-$12$ atom.


Last sentence : You ask : when $12$ grams of carbon is $\ce{6.02 10^{23}}$ ? This question has no answer, because a mass in gram cannot be equal to a simple number like $\ce{6.023 10^{23}}$.

1 amu
is A) the 1/16 of the average mass of an oxygen atom with natural isotopic conposition (variant used in chemistry) or B) the 1/16 of the mass of an oxygen-16 atom (variant used in Physics). Since 1961, as the result of unification, the unit amu has been abandoned and the new atomic mass unit u/Da (Dalton) has been introduced, based on 1/12 of carbon-12 atom mass. Some less exact textbooks still use amu where they should use u or Da.  // $\pu{1 Da} \approx \pu{1.000037 amu
(ch)} \approx \pu{1.000318 amu(f)}$

@Poutnik. Why speak about Oxygen-$16$ ? This reference to Oxygen-$16$ is old. It has been abandoned in $1961$. The present reference in Carbon-$12$

Reference to amu is as old as reference to oxygen-16. amu was abandoned as there coexisted values based on different definitions and using amu would cause confusion which it is based on. amu is deprecated and used with values based on O definition, u/Da is used with values based on carbon-12 definition.

short. quote: *....until the 1960s, chemists and physicists used two different atomic-mass scales. The chemists used an "atomic mass unit" (amu) that the natural mixture of oxygen isotopes had an atomic mass 16, while the physicists assigned the same number 16 to ... 16O. ... // The unified scale based on carbon-12... was adopted as the 'unified atomic mass unit'. The current International System of Units (SI) primary recommendation for the name of this unit is the dalton and symbol 'Da'. The name 'unified atomic mass unit' and symbol 'u' are recognized names and symbols for the same unit.

By other words - it is not the unit redefinition, but the definition of the new unit.
